# How to force Windows Phone 8 to re-load data from server

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using a HttpClient in my Windows Phone 8 Application to call a json service, get the result and show it in the current page.
To be clear, I have attached the debugguer to iis, to see when the httpclient does a call.
The problem is that the call is performed only the first time, after that data is loaded from cache and the server is not called again.

This is my design code for the button and the textblock:

```
<Button Content="Update" Click="ActualSession_Click"/>
<TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

This is the code for the button click:

```
private async void ActualSession_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string site = "http://192.168.1.17:5465/MessagesWCF/Messages.svc/Test";
            MyTextBlock.Text = "";
            MyTextBlock.Text = await Execute(site);
        }

public async Task<string> Execute(string url)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var request = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            var txt = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return txt;
        }
```

Please help me to make the button re-call the server in every click, and update the content (I have made the server give different result every time it's called to be sure that it has or not been called).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround for this is to append a different value to the querystring of the URL on each call:

```
string site = "http://192.168.1.17:5465/MessagesWCF/Messages.svc/Test?nocache=" + Guid.NewGuid();
```